# Android resources management

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I am a programmer beginner (more or less), and I was wondering what is the best way to load resources(bmps, mp3s, and so on) in Android or java in general . What I mean is that I make a class that will hold other static classes that will hold my resources(so I don't need to pass parameters when i use them, the resources can be loaded with ease and unloaded just as easy). Something like this.

```
public class ResourcesHandler {
    public static Context mContext;
    public static GraphicsCollection mGraphics;
    public static SoundFxPlayer mSoundFx;
    public static MusicPlayer mMusic;
    public static void unload() {
        mContext=null;
        mGraphics.unload();
        mSoundFx.unload();
        mMusic.unload();
    }
}
```

It probably sounds like a stupid question, but I ask mostly because I never saw something like this from someone else. I saw only resources passed back and forth or they're loaded where they need to be used. What do you think? What is the best practice?

Comment: I would suggest to use singleton with accessor methods instead of `public static`. That would make resource management much easier and safer.

Comment: Nice suggestion. It will make it safer indeed (i don't really think it will be easier).

Comment: With accessor methods you'll be able to impose some internal invariants and checks. Also, it would be easier to mock this class for tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For accomplishing that best way would be to use **Singleton** pattern since you are gonna need your Resources all the time throughout the application life cycle. Creating a Singleton class is as follows :

Static member : This contains the instance of the singleton class.

Private constructor : This will prevent anybody else to instantiate the Singleton class.

Static public method : This provides the global point of access to the Singleton object and returns the instance to the client calling class.

Also take care of of multi-threaded environment if that exists in your case.

```
public class ResourcesHandler {
    private static ResourcesHandler handlerObj;
    private Context mContext;
    private GraphicsCollection mGraphics;
    private SoundFxPlayer mSoundFx;
    private MusicPlayer mMusic;

    private ResourcesHandler(){
        //TODO
    }

    public static ResourcesHandler getInstance() {
        if (handlerObj == null){
            handlerObj = new ResourcesHandler();
        }
        return handlerObj;
    }

    public void unload(){
        mContext=null;
        if(null != mGraphics){
          mGraphics.unload();
        }
        if(null != mSoundFx){
          mSoundFx.unload();
        }
        if(null != mMusic){
          mMusic.unload();
        }                           
    }
}
```

Comment: I would check if the resources aren't null before calling `unload()` on them.

Answer (score 0):

In java in general your approach looks good enough although a lot depends on the type of program and resources you are using.

In android however, I am not convinced about your approach. Reason being that in android resources are already segregated into resources directory. and resource initialization is a lot different. Also the flow of activities would make it difficult to use this approach.